# Unable to find element after softAssert fail

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, assertions, geckodriver

Tests go on even if one of the soft asserts fails.
But in my case my test stops after a failed soft assert because next test element can't be found.

```
softAssert.assertTrue(p.OtsPage.fName().getAttribute("readonly").equals("true"), "field Name is Editable", "field Name is Read Only");
softAssert.assertTrue(p.OtsPage.fEditValue().isEnabled(), "field Edit Value is not Editable", "field Edit Value is Editable");
```

This works correctly, but if I set:

```
softAssert.assertFalse(p.OtsPage.fName().getAttribute("readonly").equals("true"), "field Name is Editable", "field Name is Read Only");
softAssert.assertFalse(p.OtsPage.fEditValue().isEnabled(), "field Edit Value is not Editable", "field Edit Value is Editable");
```

I have the following error message:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.      **For second soft assert!!!**

and tests stop.

Environment: Selenium 3.5 + geckodriver + Mozilla 56.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like not a problem with assertion, because as you mentioned second line is running but it throws exception. Your issue is probably here: `p.OtsPage.fEditValue().isEnabled()`.

To be more precise: NoSuchElementException is thrown by `WebDriver.findElement(By)` according to [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html).

You probably run `findElement()` in your `fEditValue()` function and you should search for issue there. Ensure that element denoted by selector in this function is really present on page in moment when you run it.